# ie filter using GWT ResourceBundle CSS

Tags: css, internet-explorer, gwt

I am trying to give shadow effect to a GWT DialogueBox. I applied the following style to the element

popupPanel.setStylePrimaryName("PopupPresenter");

```
.PopupPresenter{
    height:550px;
    width:700px;
    border-style:solid;
    border-width:2px;
    border-color:red;
    opacity:1.0;
     background:white none repeat scroll 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow:    4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
    box-shadow:         4px 4px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);  
  /*    For IE 8 */
     -ms-filter:literal("\"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength \=55, Direction \=135, Color \='#736F6E'),
         progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity \=100)\"");
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter:literal("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength \=55, Direction \=135, Color \='#736F6E')
    progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity \=100)");

}
```

All browsers except IE pick up the style from the CSSResourcebundle.

Same CSS works fine when I do not inject it from ResourceBundle but explicitly add up in gwt.xml after removing literal. Am I not using the gwt literal properly or am I not using the IE filter properly ?

Help Appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Are the standard attributes, like `border-style:solid`, being picked up by IE?  Does it work in IE if you remove the two IE properties?

Comment: Yes the standard attributes are picked up. Only when I use the two filters together it fails.

Answer (score 0):

What if you remove all the escapes and the comma in the `-ms-filter` after the `Shadow` filter, before the second `progid`.

```
/*    For IE 8 */ 
-ms-filter: literal("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength =55, Direction =135, Color =#736F6E) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity =100)");
/* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
filter: literal("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength =55, Direction =135, Color =#736F6E) progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(opacity =100)");
```